# A slightly rude rebus

Tags: rebus

I'm going to contribute to the rebus craze with one I invented some years ago.

The picture itself is not suitable for work - [view it directly here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nxXPb.jpg) or [view the revision history](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/revisions/10031/1) to see the image.

Alternatively, here is an emote version, but at least one of the answers - not the accepted one - relies on details from that picture which do not appear below; if you want to see the picture, please click the links above.

> **(3{ 8R**

**What phrase does this picture represent?**

Comment: Please direct meta comments to [this meta question](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/2845/15).

Comment: @Jon I've now replaced the picture with a line of text representing exactly the same thing, so no more NSFW worries! Hope this is OK.

Comment: So I was the only one who thought the picture meant "Jamie Hyneman is an ass"? Oh well.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The French word for *ass* is *CUL*. An ass with a beret and French-style moustache is fairly strongly hinting at looking for a word relating to *ass*  and certainly hints that we want something French. we have:

> **CUL8R**

This is SMS-speak for:

> SEE YOU LATER :D bye bye! tata! aufwiedersehen!

Comment: Well done my friend! You get one of my last few votes of the day. Could you explain a little more about where CUL comes from?

Comment: you want me to explain the etymology of CUL? I.e. from Latin *culus* meaning "ass"?

Comment: Now I'm wondering about the loanword "cul-de-sac". Etymologies tell me "cul" is just "bottom", but the shape makes me wonder.

Comment: @xnor the collective human mind is a weird thing... who really knows anything

Comment: Hoi, what do you mean by editing my riddle? JK :-) And no, I wasn't asking you to explain the etymology of CUL.

Comment: Can also be SMS'd as `(_._)8R`

Comment: I'll accept because this *is* the intended solution, but can you edit to make it clearer how you got CUL from the picture (and preferably spoilertag it too)?

Comment: @rand Done :D no sleep for me :p I read your other comment in tough-guy-Londoner voice btw

Answer (score 5):

This answer is probably wrong, but I will try anyway:

---

The (controversial) picture:

> "**French ass**" sounds very close to "**Friend chess**".

And about the 8 R:

> "**Eight Er**" sounds very close to "**Hater**".

So this is:

> **Friend chess hater** which could also mean **cheater**.

Comment: You're quite a long way off with this one, I'm afraid. It's nothing to do with chess! (BTW, is Gilles French?)

Comment: By the way, had you noticed you have exactly 2015 rep atm?

Comment: @randal'thor Yeah, the 2015 is cool. :)

Answer (score 4):

The Urban dictionary has a slightly rude [page](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Frog%20eater) on derogatory terms for French citizens, with the example sentence *"Those damn frog-eating asshats smell like rotten twats"*. 
The above rebus consists of

- an ass wearing a French beret and a mustache as in the old French movies
- the digit 8
- the letter R

Putting these three things together, I get **FROG** ([derogatory](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=frog) term for French), plus **EAT** (perhaps close enough to EIGHT), plus **ER** (lose enoogh to R). 
All in all, my guess would therefore be that the rebus depicts a **FROG EATER**.

Comment: I'm afraid you're not quite right, but some of your ideas are good. What sounds even more like EIGHT than EAT does? (The rebus isn't saying anything rude about French people!)

Answer (score 2):

This back part of the body camouflaged itself quite well, still we can see it's an arse.

Using the letters 'A', 'S', and 'S' or 'A', 'R', 'S' and 'E' in combination with '8' and 'R' leads towards

> ASS8R or ARSE8R

Translating those with the help of the alphabet turns into '1 19 19 8 18' or '1 18 19 5 8 18'.

> Adding those numbers up results in 65 or 51. Deal with it.

Anyway, those numbers give me nothing.

---

On the other hand, "8R" i.e. "EIGHT AR" sounds like "HATER" or "EATER".

> Now we could go for ASSHOLE and HATER. History has it, that some riddlers here are strongly opposed by the mods. Therefore the rebus could be some kind of goodbye message for the mods. I.e. describing them as the assholes and haters they like to be (from a riddler point of view).

---

However, by looking closely at colours, we can see that the characters '8' and 'R' are all black. Another thing that's black, is the moustache
(whereass the hat and the body part were coloured in many hues).

If you tried to find a letter that looks like the moustache, you'd probably find the letter 'W'.

Combining it with the other letters gives you 'W', '8' and 'R'.
In other words:

> W8R = WAITER

Comment: I'm afraid most of this is way off. You're closest with the middle part though.